# Why can't I modify an anchor's name in IHTMLDocument2?

Tags: html, powershell, dom, com, ihtmldocument2

I writing on a script that reads from a local HTML file, modifies DOM tree and then save. Instead of `Invoke-WebRequest`, using `HTMLFile` COM object seems the only way to do so.

Rewriting to other attributes like `href` works like a charm. But somehow I found it impossible to change an anchor's `name` attribute, unless recreating the whole element by setting `outerHTML` attribute which is complicated and ugly. However, `removeAttribute` method works but that's not what I want.

Test case:

```
$idoc = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$idoc.IHTMLDocument2_write("<body><a name=123></a><a name=456></a></body>")
$idoc.anchors | foreach {$_.name = "aaa"; /* or $_.setAttribute("name", "aaa") */}
# $idoc.anchors | foreach {$_.getAttribute("name")} <- changed
# $idoc.anchors | foreach {$_.outerHTML} <- remains unchanged
```

Can any one tell me is this a bug or is there just any restriction on accessing the attribute? How can I found an elegant way to do my job?

Thanks.